# Dompdf stream just downloads without dialog prompt

Tags: symfony, dompdf

I am using Dompdf in my Symfony 3 project and it's all working fine up until the point where I'm trying to get it to download. At the moment, it just downloads without a dialog prompt which is what I want, and according to the documentation, passing a value of 1 to the `Attachment` option should do this.

Here is my code:

```
$html = $this->renderView('pages/invoice_print.html.twig', array(
            'invoice' => $invoice_array
        ));

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('isHtml5ParserEnabled', true);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->setPaper('A4', 'portrait');

$dompdf->render();

$output = $dompdf->output();

$dompdf->stream("invoice_" . $invoice->getId(), array('Attachment' => 1));
```

To be honest, I was under the impression that `Attachment` was set to 1 by default - so I'm not sure what's going on. I'm using Firefox Quantum.

EDIT:

A screenshot of how the PDF will render in the browser is now attached:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with `dompdf` in the past, but, just by glancing the code on Github, I believe I see what you need.

When you invoke `stream()`, you have:

```
if (!isset($options["compress"])) $options["compress"] = true;
if (!isset($options["Attachment"])) $options["Attachment"] = true;
```

So, if no `Attachment` option is present, the option will be set to `true`

Next, on line 1311, you have:

```
$attachment = $options["Attachment"] ? "attachment" : "inline";
header(Helpers::buildContentDispositionHeader($attachment, $filename));
```

which basically boils down to a `Content-Disposition` header:

```
$contentDisposition = "Content-Disposition: $dispositionType; filename=\"$fallbackfilename\"";
```

Finally, according to the standard, if you want to serve a file inside webpage (e.g. no prompt dialog), you need to set disposition to `inline`

All being said, have you tried setting `Attachment` to `false`?

```
$dompdf->stream("invoice_" . $invoice->getId(), array('Attachment' => false));
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: If I set Attachment to 0 (which I have tried before) it just displays jumbed text on the screen (clearly trying to render the PDF to the browser but failing). The PDF does download, but just doesn't prompt the user to save it somewhere which confuses my client.

Comment: Wait, so you actually **want** file to be downloaded **without** a prompt? If that is the case, you definitely need to proceed with `'Attachment' => false`. Can you please attach a screenshot example of that garbled PDF output?

Comment: No, I need the dialog prompt. setting to false will literally try and render the PDF in the browser which fails for me. My client needs to download it but thinks it has failed as there is no direct indication it's downloaded, like most times when a dialog pops up and says "Where do you want to save this" etc.

Comment: Got it, thanks. Make sure your customer is aware that `inline` disposition downloads the file to temporary files, so he/she does not expect to find it within default downloads directory. Can you attach the screenshot please so we can get an idea of rendering failure?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of what happens if `Attachment` is set to zero.